# Foundation 6 / Bootstrap 4 - Correct way to use sass setting file in webpack

Tags: angularjs, angular, build, webpack, zurb-foundation

Project used: https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack

Foundation 6 comes with a global settings.scss file to customize the look and feel. I was wondering what is the correct way to load this in to my project.

I installed foundation-sites via NPM and added the following line to my vendor.ts

`import 'foundation-sites';`

In src/style i have the following two files
- app.scss
- _settings.scss

In app.scss i have the following code

```
@import 'settings';
@import '~foundation-sites/scss/foundation';

body {
    background: $primary-color;
}
```

This is working great. When i change the $primary-color var in settings.scss i see the desired result. So far, so good.

Now i want to add a button style to my app.component. So in app.component.scss i first did the following.

```
button {
  @include button;
}
```

That wasn't working, missing button mixin. So i added the reference to foundation to the file.

```
@import '~foundation-sites/scss/foundation';

button {
  @include button;
}
```

This works, only it is rendering the default button style from foundation and it don't respect the override i made in settings.scss. So i added the reference to settings file:

```
@import '~src/style/settings';
@import '~foundation-sites/scss/foundation';

button {
  @include button;
}
```

And it's working again. It just feels a bit cumbersome to make these two imports on each component. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: were you every able to figure this out? I trying to do something similar with vue.js and webpack.

Comment: Sadly, no. Next week I have time to look more in to this issue. Keep you posted.

Comment: Try adding the button mixin as the last line in the first settings file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I organize my code and I don't need to add the extra @import's

application.scss

```
@import './foundation';
@import './componentA';
...
```

foundation.scss:

```
@import './settings/settings';
@import '~foundation-sites/scss/foundation';
@include foundation-everything;
```

componentA.scss

```
a {
  @include button;
}
```

I just @import 'application' and I don't have to re-import foundation in each component.